# How to use a static import in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to declare a static import in Android Studio like so:

```
 import static com.example.constants.Preferences.*;
```

but as soon as I go to the next line, Android Studio folds it like this:

```
import com.example.constants.*;
```

How do I make Android Studio let me decide how to import stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellij separates static imports in default. Go to Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports and untick "Layout static imports separately". It might help...